# policy of rabbitmq delivering message when consumer crash down

Tags: crash, rabbitmq, rpc

I open 2 rpc client and 20 rpc servers in localhost, like the example in the following rabbitmq official website.
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Assume a simple example that if I send x="0" from the rpc client, the rpc server will get the message x and then compute x/x.

The rpc server will crash because of divide 0 by 0.Then the message x="0" will deliver to the next rpc server ,which server will get the message x="0" and crash down.Like dominoes game,the other 18 servers,will crash one by one.
(The real crash error is very complex in the project ,can't be catched ,and the crash reason is not because of rabbitmq)

One error message,and all the 20 rpc server will crash down one by one.

Is there any policy to avoid this happened in rabbitmq?Just like,it will deliver three times to the servers(also crash down 3 servers),then stop delivering and drop the message?